# How to prevent Access subform scroll bar from pushing content

Tags: scrollbar, ms-access-2013, subform

I have a subform with scrollbars set to vertical only. When the subform fills with enough records for the scrollbar to appear, it pushes all content of the subform to the left. It didn't use to do this and I on't know why it is doing it now. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased the width of the form my subform is based off of to be at least the width of the subform. I'm guessing this was what caused the issue?